# Probability density function for the normalised sum of N random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, generating-functions, random

I was wondering what the PDF looks like for Z= (1/N)*SUM(z_1+...+ z_n), where each z_i is computationally represented by RAND(). What is the behaviour of the PDF as N -> infinity?

Comment: relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Also, it helps if you would provide your thoughts and anything you may have tried. Regards

Comment: And what do you propose that RAND() represents? A standard Uniform random variate? A unit of currency in South Africa? Or something else? And in what language?

Comment: RAND() represents a standard uniform variate, as your top guess suggests anyway. Thank you.

Comment: @vangelis well if you have a program that generates random numbers, from your desired density, ... why not generate some, add them up, and see what it 'looks like'??

Comment: @Wolfies. I actually know what it looks like, I was just curious to know what its analytical expression looks like. Also, if there are any interesting relations to other known pdfs. From a computational point  of view I can easily appreciate the shape of the pdf: It becomes sharper towards the middle as you increase the number of random variables. If you work with discrete variables it is not hard to actually see that in probability space the percentage of points summing to the average increases with N. But at what rate? Exponentially perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I actually know what it looks like, I was just curious to know what its analytical expression looks like.

If you are after the analytical solution:

If $Z_i$ ~ Uniform(0,1), the distribution of the sample mean is known as Bates's distribution.

Comment: Many thanks wolfies.